# Я хочу использовать BrowserRouter в своем React app. Я вложил самый верхний компонент в теги BrowserRouter, как показано ниже: Но она дает ошибку?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
     <App/>
    </BrowserRouter> 
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам как минимум нужно импортировать этот компонент

`import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'`

Comment: Спасибо большое сработало !

Comment: супер! закройте, плз вопрос (отметив галочку), чтобы не висел как открытый